# How can I get the index of a specific element in a Spinner from Python's Kivy library?

Tags: python, kivy

I am doing a university project and I have a problem. In this project I need to fill a search tree with nodes, **these nodes can be repeated in the tree**, so to choose the parent of each node, I put each one in a Kivy Spinner. So far so good, the problem comes when I add two or more equal nodes, since when choosing one of those in the spinner, it always choose the first one that I added, so the user cannot specify which of the nodes that are repeated want to use as parent.

I tried to fix it by simply choosing the node and retrieving the index of it in the spinner and thus comparing it to a unique identifier that each node has. However, I can't get the exact index of the spinner box to know exactly which of the nodes it chose.

```
def put_child_to_child(self):
        """
        Add children to nodes.
        """
        for tn.node in self.tree_nodes:
            # Here I compare the index of the spinner that is currently selected and compare it with the unique identifier of the node
             # Then when it finds it, the child will be added to the node selected in the spinner
            if self.current_selected_item == tn.node.id:
                tnode = tn.TreeNode(self.txt_new_node.text, self.node_id)
                tn.node.add_child(tnode)
                self.tree_nodes.append(tnode)
                self.actions_after_build()
                break
```

[I am going to introduce node 5 as a child of node 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/703RZ.png)

[There, child 5 child of node 10, now node 5 is available to be parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnSD9.png)

[Now I have added a couple of 5 more as children of 10... Here comes the problem... Now when choosing any of the 5 as a parent, the first will always be chosen...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3Pp.png)

I managed to recover the index, but I have been left with the same problem, since in the Kivy code what I do is recover the index of the first node it finds, that is, it looks for the index from the **text** in the spinner, it does not give me the index of the button, that the user specifically clicks...

`on_text: root.spinner_clicked (sp_current_nodes.values.index (sp_current_nodes.text))`

In the previous line of code .kv `spinner_clicked` is a method that is called when I click on a spinner box and `sp_current_nodes` is the id of the Spinner

Anyway, what I need is to retrieve the exact index of the box that the user clicks to be able to choose the parent node that the user wants from among the repeated nodes within the spinner. I would appreciate a help and I hope I have explained myself well, if it is not the case, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You are presenting your user with a list containing duplicate choices, and assuming that, by some unknown logic, the user is making an informed choice. Presenting a list of duplicate choices is a bad software design. The real problem is how to present the choices that clearly identifies the different choices.

Comment: Yes! Of course, but I didn't have much time so I just want it to do that way, because in other languages like Visual Basic or C# it is possible, but I'm new in Python and Kivy. Thank you!

Comment: Since the difference appears to be the parent node, why not add the parent node name to the spinner values, like `parent/child`?

Comment: Mmm I think I don't understand what you mean. Put the list of parents and their children in the same button of the spinner?